# Modify %in% operator to find an object in a list

Tags: r, list

I have to modify `%in%` operator which will find an objects in a list.

I have a list:
`list1 <- list(c(5,6), 6, list(2, c(5, 6)), "string")`

Non-modified `%in%` operator after testing these values:

```
c(5,6) %in% list1
6 %in% list1
2 %in% list1
list(2, c(5,6)) %in% list1
```

will return:

```
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE
```

but for `list(2, c(5,6)) %in% list1` I need it to return `TRUE` as it is an element of this list.

I have to implement it without using loops and I got stuck.

Comment: `foo = list(2, c(5, 6)); lapply(list1, function(x) identical(x, foo))`

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to detect `list(2, c(5,6))` in `list1` or does it necessarily have to be through a modification of `%in%`?

Comment: Similar to @d.b 's method: `f <- function(myVec) any(sapply(list1, function(x) identical(x, myVec)))` will return TRUE for something like myVec == foo in the above comment.

Comment: @d.b thank you a lot, it worked fine for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`purrr::has_element` should give you what you want:

```
purrr::has_element(list1, c(5,6))
#[1] TRUE
purrr::has_element(list1, 6)
#[1] TRUE
purrr::has_element(list1, 2)
#[1] FALSE
purrr::has_element(list1, list(2, c(5,6)))
#[1] TRUE
```

You could also write your own infix function that wraps around this function and works like `%in%`:

```
`%in2%` <- function(lhs, rhs) purrr::has_element(rhs, lhs)

c(5,6) %in2% list1
#[1] TRUE
6 %in2% list1
#[1] TRUE
2 %in2% list1
#[1] FALSE
list(2, c(5,6)) %in2% list1
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

In case all you want is to detect this element in the list rather than necessarily defining an operator, there is no need for anything fancy; we can simply add another `list` as to make it clear that it's a single element that we are interested in:

```
list(list(2, c(5,6))) %in% list1
# [1] TRUE
```

---

**Update:** while this may be intuitive, what exactly is happening isn't so clear. As @BenBolker observed, `%in%` is based on `match`, whose description says

> Factors, raw vectors and lists are converted to character vectors, and
>   then x and table are coerced to a common type (the later of the two
>   types in R's ordering, logical < integer < numeric < complex <
>   character) before matching.

So, it would seem that `list(list(2, c(5,6)))` and `list1` first get (somehow) converted to character vectors. As we need to maintain the structure and ordering one sensible guess that it directly means

```
as.character(list(list(2, c(5,6)))) %in% as.character(list1)
```

where

```
as.character(list(list(2, c(5,6))))
# [1] "list(2, c(5, 6))"

as.character(list1)
# [1] "c(5, 6)"          "6"                "list(2, c(5, 6))" "string"
```

Comment: interesting. I think I see why this works (Details of `?"%in%"` explain that in `match()` (which `%in%` is based on),  lists are converted to character vectors before matching); it would be nice to explain/illustrate

Comment: @BenBolker, interesting indeed. I updated the answer with some guesses.