# How to find if a list contains a null value in R?

Tags: r

%in% does not work as logically expected:

```
> 1 %in% list(1,NULL,3)
[1] TRUE
> NULL %in% list(1,NULL,3)
logical(0)
```

How can I get a TRUE response if a list contains a NULL element?

Comment: Regarding "'`%in%` does not work as logically expected", please see  `help("%in%")`: "lists are converted to character vectors, and then `x` and `table` are coerced to a common type" (where `%in%` is defined as `match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0`).

Comment: Related post: [Modify %in% operator to find an object in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54245504/modify-in-operator-to-find-an-object-in-a-list), where the "wrapping-in-list solution" is given, but, as I commented above, with a caution on coercion. There's also a `purrr` alternative (`has_element`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also wrap your NULL in a `list()` and it seems to work

```
> list(NULL) %in% list(1,3)
[1] FALSE

> list(NULL) %in% list(1,NULL,3)
[1] TRUE

> list(NULL) %in% list(Inf,-Inf,numeric(0),NA, NaN)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: This one is definitely better. Is there any unexpected condition where it could break?

Comment: None of the usual suspects break it. `list(NULL) %in% list(Inf,-Inf,numeric(0),NA,NaN)` gives `FALSE`

Comment: Thank you. This is absolutely precious.

Comment: I found one small potential issue `list(NULL) %in% list(123,"NULL")` returns `TRUE` However testing `identical(NULL,"NULL")` returns `FALSE` I'm not an expert on the differences between the two. I might ask SO myself.

Comment: @DanielO Please see `?"%in%"`: "lists are converted to character vectors, and then `x` and `table` are coerced to a common type" (where `%in%` is defined as `match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0`). So caution against _any_ coercion surprise.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `is.null` in `sapply`:

```
any(sapply(list(1,NULL,3), is.null))
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: this approach is a lot faster than using `match`/`%in%`

Comment: @user20650 As @Henrik already mentioned in his comment. When using `%in%` *lists are converted to character vectors* what will need some time.

Answer (score 2):

Base R using Map:

```
any(unlist(Map(is.null, lst)))
```

Base R using mapply:

```
any(mapply(is.null, lst, SIMPLIFY = TRUE))
```

Data:

```
lst <- list(1,NULL,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can lapply/sapply the list to check where the length is = 0

```
> sapply( list(1,NULL,3), function(x) length(x) == 0 )
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

You then can wrap that in `any()`

Comment: Why would I want to perform a massive lapply to every element of a potentially long list just to check if it contains null?

Comment: @StefanoBorini Because it answers your question directly. If you don't like the answer, please provide clarification to your requirements.

Comment: using length would incorrectly flag zero length vectors ie.e `list(1,numeric(0),3)`

Comment: No it just shocks me that the language does not provide a consistent behavior on containment inquire, and that there's no actual method to do it without relying on a workaround.